# Data structure for a media playlist?

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list, media-player, playlist

At the first sight double linked list seems reasonable, but as I started implementing I've faced problem tracking current position. I've used std::list iterator but dealing with extreme cases (see next part) became a pain.
So here are requirements for a DS:

- Preserve elements' order
- Effective insertion in the middle
- Insertions/erases don't invalidate iterators
- O(N) random access is not a problem

Linked list suits best for it.

Requirements for a current position cursor (iterator):

- Bidirectional
- Initially denotes `end` position
- When iterator in the `end` position, after inserting element in the end, next iterator advance will move it to this element. The same behavior if previously the playlist was empty
- Same for the opposite case: iterator in the beginning, `push_front`, moving backwards will go the newly added element

What are the best practices to implement it? Is there's any libraries for it (C++)?

Comment: std::list sounds perfect. what's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::list` is a container that supports constant time insertion and removal of elements from anywhere in the container. Fast random access is not supported(Which is not a problem in your case). It is usually implemented as a doubly-linked list. Compared to `std::forward_list` this container provides bidirectional iteration capability while being less space efficient.

Addition, removal and moving the elements within the list or across several lists does not invalidate the iterators or references. An iterator is invalidated only when the corresponding element is deleted.

From My point of view `std::list` is perfect fit for the problem described by you.

Comment: Silly me: There's a structure consisting of std::list and std::list::iterator. Default copyctor made a deep copy of the list, but iterator was still pointing to the old one.